# SQL query in R passing two dates as parameters

Tags: sql, r, db2

I have a `begin.date` and `end.date`, I want to retrieve rows from a db2 table between these two dates.

When I run the query by hardcoding these values, it works fine.

```
Data   =   dbGetQuery(conn, paste(
          "
          Select * From tableA
          WHERE DATE(Administered_Date) between '01-01-2011'  AND '01-31-2011' 
          "))
```

But when I pass these two dates as parameters, not hardcoding them, I get an syntax error. This is my attempt so far. If anybody can tell me where I am going wrong, it will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
 library(RJDBC)
 i <- '0'
 begin.date = as.Date("2011-01-01") + as.numeric(i) + as.numeric('0')
 end.date   = as.Date("2011-01-01") + as.numeric(i) + as.numeric('31')

     Data   =   dbGetQuery(conn, paste(
      "
      Select * From tableA
      WHERE DATE(Administered_Date) between '", begin.date,"'"  AND '", end.date, "'" 
      "))
```

Comment: Side note: Please don't use `BETWEEN` with date/time/timestamp types.  Since they're a positive, contiguous-range type, you should be using an exclusive upper-bound (that is, `<`).  Additionally, if at all possible you shouldn't call a function on a database column in the `WHERE` clause (or `JOIN` conditions), because it prevents the database from using an index.  Instead, try to call it on the constant side; your query should probably read `WHERE administered_date >= TIMESTAMP(:beginDate, '00:00:00' AND administered_date < TIMESTAMP(:endDate, '00:00:00')`.

Comment: Curious @JillSellum...I see you accepted a different answer than mine which is fine. For future readers though please advise if the parameterized query I suggested worked. I unfortunately cannot test with `db2` or `RJDBC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `paste` function inserts spaces by default, turning your string into

```
Select * From tableA
      WHERE DATE(Administered_Date) between ' 01-01-2011 '  AND , ' 01-31-2011 '
```

Instead use `paste0`.  Or continue using `paste` and set the `sep` parameter to a blank string:

```
 Data   =   dbGetQuery(conn, paste(
      "
      Select * From tableA
      WHERE DATE(Administered_Date) between '", begin.date,"'"  AND , '", end.date, "'" 
      ",
      sep = ""))
```

Comment: that did not work. I get an error.                                       
           `Error: unexpected symbol in:
"                          and Administered_Date 
                          AND DATE(Administered_Date ) between between '", begin.date,"'"  AND"
>       ",
+     sep = "")
+ `

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help.  With such things, I always find it useful to stored the SQL statement in a variable.  Output the variable to your usual SQL interface (Microsoft SQL Enterprise Manager for me) and see if it works.  That way, you'll know if your problem is string translation or something more sinister related to R

Comment: Um, you should never directly concatenate parameters into a query string, since that invites SQL Injection.  Is it limited here, since presumably the dates are typed (ie, not arbitrary strings)?  Sure; but it's better craftsmanship to do it with all variables, and it would have solved the problem, too (and any potential issues with text formats).

Answer (score 6):

Simply use parameterized queries as discussed on  [RJDBC page](http://www.rforge.net/RJDBC/) for prepared statements. More than insulating from SQL injection, you abstract data (R) from code (SQL) without messy string concatenation and quote enclosures for enhanced maintainability and readability:

```
SQLstring <- "SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE DATE(Administered_Date) BETWEEN ? AND ?"

Data <- dbGetQuery(conn, SQLstring, begin.date, end.date)
```

*Possibly dates need to be coerced to `as.character()` to avoid being read as integers*.